# C shmat in function

Tags: c, posix, shared-memory

I want to create a function that creates and attaches a shared memory in C. When I do it in `main`, it works fine but when I put the same code in a function the `shmat` returns `NULL`.

```
int main() { 

    int data=0; 
    int* shm_data=NULL; 
    int shmid; 

    if ( ( shmid = shmget( SMKEY_data, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT  | 0666 ) ) < 0) { 
        perror("Shmget Faild (shmid) "); 
        exit(3); 
    } 

    if ( (shm_data = shmat(shmid, 0, 0)) == (int *) - 1) { 
         perror("Shmat Faild (shm_data) "); 
         exit(4); 
    } 
    *shm_data = data; 

    printf("1: %d\n", *shm_data); 

    if ( fork() == 0 ) { 
        (*shm_data)++; 
    } 
    else { 
        int s; 
        wait(&s); 
        printf("2: %d\n", *shm_data); 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1:0
2:1
```

---

```
void doshm(int* shmid, int* shm_data, int* data) { 
    if ( ( (*shmid) = shmget( SMKEY_data, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT  | 0666 ) ) < 0) { 
        perror("Shmget Faild (shmid) "); 
        exit(3); 
    } 

    if ( (shm_data = shmat( (*shmid), 0, 0)) == (int *) - 1) { 
         perror("Shmat Faild (shm_data) "); 
         exit(4); 
    } 
    *shm_data = *data; 
} 

int main() {
    int data=0; 
    int* shm_data=NULL; 
    int shmid; 

    doshm(&shmid, shm_data, &data); 

    printf("1: %d\n", *shm_data); 

    if ( fork() == 0 ) { 
        (*shm_data)++; 
    } 
    else { 
        int s; 
        wait(&s); 
        printf("2: %d\n", *shm_data); 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: interesting. can you find out where the segmentation fault occurs, e.g. by using gdb?

Comment: yes! at printf when return's from the function because the shm_data is null!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shm_data` is initialized to `NULL` and never reassigned, pass it by reference to `doshm` like this

```
doshm(&shmid, &shm_data, &data);
```

and then change the signature of `doshm` to

```
doshm(int* shmid, int** shm_data, int* data)
```

and finally, remove this line from `doshm`

```
*shm_data = *data
```

also, check for `shm_data == NULL` after `doshm`, before `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

when you write

```
doshm(&shmid, shm_data, &data);
```

and then you change the value of `shm_data` within `doshm`

```
if ( (shm_data = shmat(shmid, 0, 0)) == (int *) - 1) { ... }
```

then this change will operate on a local copy of the variable, and this change is not applied to the version that lives in the scope of `main`, where `shm_data` will still be `NULL`.